# Remove the default phone number sample while entering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[Sample site](http://www.crabapplefbc.org/Small-Business-Directory).

The above is the sample site. Please look at the phone number textfield in that site.

How are they doing such thing?

How to show the default phone number format value in the phone number text field, 
and how to remove that format while user entering the phone number?

Is there any jQuery function there, or do we have to research and start the work?

Comment: This is called a MaskedTextBox in the Microsoft World.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [jQuery Masked Input](http://www.conetrees.com/2009/03/blog/jquery-masked-input-plugin-increase-usability-for-masked-format-input-fields/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a watermark plugin built using jQuery. There are a lot of samples in this page.

**[jQuery watermark plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-text-watermark)**

See Demo in

[jQuery Watermark - Example](http://mario.ec/static/jq-watermark/)

Answer (score 0):

You may also find this helpfull. I use this technique lately

http://www.zurb.com/playground/inline-form-labels

Answer (score 0):

It works with [watermark textfield](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo).